# Regular expression for removing the first line of text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have googled and checked several resources, but the last 2 hours of trial and error is no good.

I have many hundres of files in which I need to remove the first line of text

As for now I have this regular expression to get the first line of text:

**(\A[^\n]*\n)**

But I want to have a condition in my Regular expression, that the first line ALSO MUST contain this **GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]**

Because not ALL first lines in every file should be replaced.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove that first line containing the `GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]` as a literal string, use

```
\A.*GLOBALS\["\\x61\\156\\x75\\156\\x61"].*\r?\n
```

[image]

Note that `.` matches any character but a newline, and `\r?` will also match Windows style line breaks (if you have any). Backslahses must be doubled if you need to match a literal backslash. The square bracket `[` is also a regex metacharacter, and must also be escaped (`\[`).

Comment: Incredibly simple, but none the less hard for me. Thanks! 2 hours of my google and trial was not at half as great as your answer!

Comment: One thing I learnt recently: `[^\n]*` is not that fast as `.*`. You only have to use `[^\n]` when you are using an `(?s)` single line (dotall) modifier.